# Are users with racist responses supposed to be banned?

Tags: support

In [this response](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46777/13808), aside from a complete misunderstanding of the problem, the user also mistakenly thinks that I'm "antifeminist" and (having looked up my profile) concluded that this must be due to my Arab background.

Shouldn't this user be banned for bigoted statements?

Answer (score 4):

First: Yes, the user should be suspended for this behaviour and has been.

I, personally, do not think it is because having been bigoted, but because the tone went way out of any reasonable limit. You can be bigoted and still watch your tone. But you cannot use increasingly insulting language, bigoted or not.

That been said: For the next time, please try to just flag and omit any comment. It escalated quickly and it's been close to giving enough reason for suspending your account as well (even if it would have been for a shorter period of time). I know it is hard, but it is like the wise men said:

**Do not feed the troll!**

Comment: The troll is back under a different user name. It's requiring Jedi levels of self-control for me to not re-engage.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing: The force is strong with you, young padawan. Thank you for your cooperation. Cannot do much more than deleting twin accounts atm, though (would have been faster if moderation on mobiles would be included into the app and not such a pain in the...nevermind).

Comment: @AlexanderSKing did the comments get deleted? i didn't read the comment thread, just wondered what happens to stuff like that